# Java How to destroy Singleton instance

Tags: java, singleton

I have a singleton that is created like that

```
private static class SingletonHolder { 
    public static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
}
```

I'd like to reset the singleton instance at a certain time. (I'm sure at this time it is safe to reset the singleton instance). I tried to remove the final specifier and set the instance to null when I want to reset it but the problem is how to get another instance (It will remain null)

Another question is is it safe to remove the final specifier inside the SingletonHolder.

Thanks

Comment: so who is going to reset the singleton state? the singleton class or from external guys?!

Comment: In this case (needing a completely fresh object instance) I think you don't need singleton, but a factory.

Comment: Your current class is not a singleton at all. It still has a `public` constructor.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `reset` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you **really** need to reset a singleton instance (which doesn't makes much sense actually) you could wrap all its inner members in a private object, and reinitialize via an explicit `initialize()` and `reset()` methods.
That way, you can preserve your singleton istance and provide some kind of "reset" functionality.

Comment: That sounds good. Actually I though of resetting to a new instance instead of null. The thing is that I'm one hundred percent sure at resetting time only one thread will be accessing the singleton. Thanks for help.

Comment: In this case the singleton is still not null. i mean if you call getInstance() you will get the same instance again ...

Answer (score 2):

you would provide a package-visible(default access level) method for other classes to be able to reset the singleton, something like this

```
class SingleGuy{
 private static SingleGuy=new SingleGuy();//eager init mode
 synchronized static void initTheGuy(){
  SingleGuy=new SingleGuy();//while this not recommended!
 }
 synchronized static void resetTheInstance(){
  /*Reset the singleton state as you wish. just like you reinitialized*/
 } 
}
```